# Возможно ли узнать размер буффера сокет, до вызова read()/recv()?

Tags: c, сокет, unix

Возможно ли узнать размер данных буфера сокет или первого в очереди пакета, до вызова read()/recv(), или это невозможно и единственным выходом является создавать массив с запасом? для файлов это возможно с помощью структуры stat.

Comment: Данные в TCP-сокетах не делятся на пакеты. Если придёт несколько пакетов, они будут слеплены в один поток данных. Так что предположу, что вы хотите не того, что вам на самом деле нужно. Или у вас UDP или что-то ещё?

Comment: @andreymal, мне нужно просто узнать ,сколько данных в данные момент в буфере до вызова read

Comment: В сокете может не быть ничего до вызова read. Или от момента запроса размера до окончания чтения может придти что-то еще. Кроме того, если буфер выделять самому, то может получиться избежать копирования за счет сохранения данных прямо в собственноручно выделенном буфере.

Comment: [пожалуйста, обратите внимание на количество букв «ф» в слове «буфер»](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80).

Comment: Для получения количества доступных данных попробуйте [ioctl](https://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/sasc/doc700/html/lr2/ioctl.htm)(sock, **FIONREAD**, &int_num_of_bytes);

Comment: Если вас интересует текущий размер буфера, то пробуйте [getsockopt](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html)(sock, SOL_SOCKET, **SO_RCVBUF**, &int_rcvBufferSize, &int_sockOptSize);  / не забудьте инициализировать `int int_sockOptSize = sizeof(int);`